# How to subtract values generated from two tables?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

```
price
2.22
10.32
0.4
22.95
8.56

price
1.57
3.0
0.35
9.52
5.56
```

I have two tables which contain prices of product sales. One table contains data from October and another from November. I am looking for a query to generate the change in revenue generated from October to November.

Query used:

```
select sum(a.price) - sum(b.price) as REVENUE_DIFF
from ((select sum(price) nov_data_part  where event_type='purchase') a
      UNION ALL (select sum(price) from oct_data_part  where event_type='purchase') b);
```

This is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select n.nov_sum  - o.oct_sum as REVENUE_DIFF
from (select sum(n.price) as nov_sum
      from nov_data_part n
      where event_type = 'purchase'
     ) n cross join
     (select sum(o.price) as oct_sum
      from oct_data_part n
      where event_type = 'purchase'
     ) o;
```

As a note:  You have a real problem with your data model if you are splitting rows across different tables based on the month.